# read: Illegal option -s in shell scripting

Tags: bash, shell

I tried running this code:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -s "Password: " password
```

With command:

```
run sh init.sh
```

it throws an error: `read: Illegal option -s`. Any help.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ruby.

Comment: So what about shell ?

Answer (score 18):

I take it you're using Debian/Ubuntu, or a BSD-derivative?

When you execute a command like `run sh init.sh` (although I'm not myself familiar with this `run` command) you are overriding the `#!/bin/bash` shebang. In your case `sh` is a strictly compliant POSIX shell like `dash`, where, in fact, the only argument to `read` that is not an extension is `-r`.

So maybe you'd want to use `run bash init.sh` instead?

Comment: Is there a way to enforce the shebang? If I'm giving a script to others and would prefer not to have to remind them "don't run this with `sh script.sh`, it has to be `./script.sh`".

Comment: @rococo There's not a way to "enforce" a shebang. Shebangs are only evaluated when the script itself it `exec`'d. If an issue of not having to remind people, I'd recommend renaming the script `init.bash`.